# In a UWP application how show bounding box on CameraCaptureUI?

Tags: c#, uwp

IN UWP trying to capture the image using CameraCaptureUI.

```
var ccu = new CameraCaptureUI();
ccu.PhotoSettings.AllowCropping = false;
ccu.PhotoSettings.Format = CameraCaptureUIPhotoFormat.Jpeg;
ccu.PhotoSettings.MaxResolution = CameraCaptureUIMaxPhotoResolution.HighestAvailable;
StorageFile imageFile = await ccu.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);
```

it will be good if we can show the user a bounding box to the user. So they know the area of the image captured. But currently there is no option or method provided in CameraCaptureUI to draw bounding box. Pl. let us know if there is any options to draw bounding box while capturing the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to say, currently, there is not such api could add bounding box for `CameraCaptureUI`. And this api was called system camera app to get image. It has not provide to many option. please feel free post your requirement with windows feed back hub.

Another workaround is custom camera capture and add this bounding box. For related document, please refer to  [Basic photo, video, and audio capture with MediaCapture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-my/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/basic-photo-video-and-audio-capture-with-mediacapture#capture-a-photo-to-a-file). [Here](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/main/Samples/CameraStarterKit) is code sample that you could refer to.